# How do I go from fixed width to percentage width in a CSS stylesheet?

Tags: css

I want a div to be responsive and adjust itself to 100% width of my screen if I resize my viewport to 640 pixels or less.  So I wrote this CSS

```
div.mypanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 570px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #00295E;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 640px;) { div.mypanel { width : 100%; } }
```

Only problem is... it doesn't seem to work unless the `div.mypanel` is set to a width that is a percentage, and I don't want a percentage.

Is this somehow not allowed by some obscure definition of CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you have a `;` after your `max-width` which is not proper syntax for media queries. Remove it and it should work as expected.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nj16vsr0/)

Comment: Thanks.  Moments after I posted I realized that was the error too.  It is working now.